# Prime ideals in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, ring-theory, ideals

Are there any prime ideals in the ring $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which are not maximal?
Perhaps, I duplicate smb's question, but this is an interesting problem!
Could you give me any hint or give a link to some literature?

Comment: See on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83062/non-maximal-prime-ideal-in-the-ring-of-continuous-functions

Comment: @martini: That MO question is rather different since it asks about the ring of continuous functions on the *open* interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35793

Answer (score 12):

If $R$ is a reduced commutative ring, then the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\dim(R)=0$
2. Every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal.
3. For every $a \in R$ we have $(a^2)=(a)$.
4. For every $a \in R$ there is some unit $u \in R$ such that $ua$ is idempotent.

In that case, $R$ is called von Neumann regular. The proof of the equivalences is not so hard. 1. $\Leftrightarrow$ 2. is trivial, 2. $\Rightarrow$ 3. may be reduced to the case of a reduced $0$-dimensional local ring, which has to be a field, for which the claim is obvious, $3. \Rightarrow 2.$ If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal, in $R/\mathfrak{p}$ we have $a \equiv a^2 b$ for some $b$, hence $a \equiv 0$ or $1 \equiv ab$, which shows that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field. I leave the equivalence to $4.$ as an exercise.

Applying this to $R=C(K)$ for a perfectly normal space $K$, we see that $\dim(R)=0$ iff $K$ is finite discrete (use that every closed subset of $K$ is the zero set of some $f \in C(K)$, which has to be open-closed by 4.).

In particular, $C[0,1]$ has (lots of) prime ideals which are not maximal. But I don't think that you can write them down explicitly. One can show that every norm-closed prime ideal is maximal (for example using Gelfand duality).

Comment: I wonder if "you can't write them down explicitly" can be made precise?  Can we say something in terms of descriptive set theory about the complexity of a non-maximal prime ideal?  Is it, say, consistent with ZF+DC that none exist?

Answer (score 7):

Here's just one example.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence that converges to a point $x$, and let $U$ be an [ultrafilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\mathbb{N}$. Intuitively, an ultrafilter is just a funny way of dividing the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ into "small" and "large". So let $I$ be the ideal of functions $f$, such that $\{n | f(x_n) = 0\}$ is in $U$, i.e. that have, according to $U$, "many zeroes".

You can check, from the definition of ultrafilter, that this is indeed a prime ideal (basically because the intersection of two large sets is large and the union of two small sets is small). Now if the ultrafilter is not principal (i.e. not generated by one of those points) then the ideal won't be maximal.

Comment: Because of the choice of the free ultrafilter this fits to my remark "But I don't think that you can write them down explicitly".

Comment: Another solution (which may use an ultrafilter in disguise) is given here : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/784181/29335. It also illustrates the elusiveness of the example prime ideal.

Answer (score 7):

another way to construct a prime wich is not maximal is the following:

Consider the multiplicative set of continuos function having just a finite number of zeros in [0,1]. Since this is a multiplicative set not containing 0 there's a prime ideal not intersecting him. But then since it does not intersect him, it cannot be the set of functions that kills one point(indeed the function $x-pt$ has finite number of 0(just 1) and is in that ideal): but those are all the maximals(by the Banach "nullstellensatz")

Comment: By the way also here i'm using choice axiom because to prove the existence of such a prime(not intersecting a maximal sistem) one uses Zorn lemma. So it fits still the remark of Martin Brandenburg. But since i don't know anything about ultrafilters, it seemed worth posting.

Comment: I don-t know why this has been down voted.

Comment: Nor do I: this example is much more explicit, and easier to understand, than the other answers. +1

Answer (score 3):

Fix a point $c\in (0, 1)$. Define $I := \{ f \in C[0,1] : Z(f)$ contains an open nbd of $c \}$ where $Z(f)$ denotes the zero set of $f$. It can be easily checked that $I$ is a radical ideal and $I \subsetneq M_c := \{ f \in C[0,1] : f(c) = 0 \}$. Also note that $I \nsubseteq M_b$ for any $b \in [0, 1], b\neq c$. Now use the following fact: In a commutative ring with unity, a radical ideal is an intersection of prime ideals. So, $I$ is an intersection of prime ideals, but clearly it's not an intersection of maximal ideals only. Thus there must exists at least one non-maximal prime.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, I didn't see the link that you gave above.These two proofs are essentially same.

Comment: Aren't you assuming here that the only maximal ideals of C[0,1] are of the form $M_x$?