# Prime ideal of the ring of continuous functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be the ring of continuous maps $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that there exists a prime ideal $Q \in \operatorname{Spec} (A)$ which is not of the form $I_p = \{ f \in A \mid f(p)=0 \}$ with $p \in [0,1]$.

Hint: use localization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the ideal $J\subset  A$ of functions $f\in A$ such that  the limit for $x$ tending to $\frac 12$ (but remaining $\neq \frac 12$ ) of $\frac {f(x)}{(x-\frac 12)^r}$ is $0$ for all $r=1,2,3,...$ .
Then $J$ is not prime, but is a reduced ideal (i.e. equal to its nilradical) .
So $J$ is the intersection of the prime ideals containing it.
Since the only $I_p$ containing $J$ is $I_{\frac 12}$ there and since $J\neq I_{\frac 12}$ there must exist some prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$ with $\mathfrak p\neq I_p$ for all $p\in [0,1]$.

**Remark: why $J$ is not prime**
Consider in $A$ the functions $f(x)= \operatorname {max} (0,x-\frac 12)$ and $g(x)= \operatorname {max} (0,\frac 12 -x)$.
Then $fg=0\in J$ although  $f,g\notin J$. Hence the ideal $J$ is not prime.

Comment: How would you ensure that such ideal is not $I_0$ or $I_1$?

Comment: @Pavel: you are right. I have corrected my answer by furnishing prime ideals different from all $I_p$'s

Comment: The nilradical of $J$ consists of the $f\in A$ which have some power in $J$: $\exists N, f^N\in J$.

Comment: It is **a** radical. There exists another radical, the intersection of the maximal ideals containing the ideal, which is called the Jacobson radical.

Comment: why is $J = nil(J)$ ?

Comment: I think $J=0$. Is it true?

Comment: @gregoryduran No, $J$ contains e.g. $\exp \left(-\frac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}\right)$, where the value at $\frac{1}{2}$ is understood to be $0$. If a power of $f$ vanishes faster than every power of $(x-\frac12)$, then $f$ itself must vanish faster than every power, therefore $J = \sqrt{J}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Daniel: I couldn't have said it as well as you!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Why $I_{1/2}$ is the only $I_p$ containing $J$?

Comment: @karparvar : Because Daniel's exponential function  function in the comment above is in $J$ but in no  $I_p$ except  $I_{1/2}$ .

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the hint was to “use localization” and that the other answer does not seem to have utilized it. Just today I saw someone mention the probable desired trick, and it seems too ingenious not to share.   Here it is.

Take $S$ to be the subset of nonzero polynomial functions restricted to $[0,1]$. It is a mutiplicative set.  Therefore by basic commutative algebra, there is a prime ideal disjoint from $S$.  Clearly $P$ is not of the form described, since to do so would require it to contain $x-a$ for some $a\in[0,1]$.