# Non Maximal Prime ideal!

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Assume $S$ to be all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. I know by compactness of $[0,1]$ it follows that
all maximal ideals of $S$ have the form $M_{x_0}=\{f\in S \mid f(x_0)=0\}$.Does there exist any non maximal prime ideal of $S$.I tried with some ideals of S but could not find any.please give me some idea how can I construct this?

Comment: Please also add to your list of "things to do before asking a question" a thorough search of our questions that already exist.  This is the third question you've asked recently that could be considered a duplicate. I found this one by googling "site: math.stackexchange.com maximal prime ideal continuous functions".

Comment: @rschwieb, Good point! I guess I should have searched before answering, as well. In any case, I don't think my example has been written down as an answer to the other question!

Comment: @rschwieb,My mistake! although i din't searched on stack exchange but i searched on google and i din't find any satisfacory answer.

Comment: @Stephen Unless I'm just fooled by similarities, I think your approach was already used [at this other duplicate of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/784181/29335).

Comment: @ArpitKansal Actually the site search worked pretty well in this case, too. I put in "prime maximal continuous function" and the duplicate was fourth on the list.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks, but you're giving me too much credit! My idea definitely doesn't work.