# C(0, 1) has infinitely many prime ideals not of the form Mp

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I know $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ has all maximal ideals of the form $M_p=\{f\in \mathcal C([0, 1]) : f(p) =0,\  p\in [0, 1] \}$. My question is little bit different.  If I replace $[0, 1]$ by $(0, 1)$  then how can I show that this ring has infinitely many prime ideals not of the form $M_p$ ?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784158/ring-of-continuous-maps-and-prime-ideals) is also related.

Answer (score 1):

In the only answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078755/finding-a-space-x-such-that-dim-cx-n) thread, Eric Wofsey defines in a more general context $P_k$ which will be a prime ideal in a ring of the form $\mathcal C(X)$. This can be applied to your case, and actually shows that $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ itself has infinitly many prime ideals which are not of the form $M_p$.